# Electromagnetic waves at interface between dielectrics

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics textbook claims that the simple existence of boundary conditions (doesn't matter which they are) between incident, reflected and refracted waves that must be satisfied at every points of the interface and at every time leads to

$$\omega=\omega '=\omega '' $$

$$(\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x})_{z=0}=(\mathbf{k}'\cdot \mathbf{x})_{z=0}=(\mathbf{k}''\cdot \mathbf{x})_{z=0} $$

where $\omega$ and $\mathbf{k}$ are respectively the angular frequency and the wave vector of the incident wave, $\omega'$ and $\mathbf{k}'$ of the refracted wave and $\omega''$ and $\mathbf{k}''$ of the reflected wave.
$z=0$ identifies the interface between two different dielectrics materials.

I really can't see how these relations are found. Can someone please show me the math behind?

EDIT:

Let's say I ignore what Jackson says and I use the continuity condition for the electric fields

$$ \mathbf{E}e^{i(\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}-\omega t)}+ \mathbf{E}''e^{i(\mathbf{k}''\cdot \mathbf{x}-\omega'' t)}=\mathbf{E}'e^{i(\mathbf{k}'\cdot \mathbf{x}-\omega' t)} $$

This one holds only if there's not surface charge on the interface.
Does that means that if there's some surface charge the above relations are false and then also the Snell's law is false?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is required for the electric field to be a consistent and continuous function across the boundary. If you add together all of the waves on either side, you get an equation that looks essentially of the form
$$
A_\mathrm{i}e^{i(k_x^{(\mathrm{i})}x-\omega^{(\mathrm{i})}t)}+ A_\mathrm{r}e^{i(k_x^{(\mathrm r)}x-\omega^{(\mathrm r)}t)} = A_\mathrm{t}e^{i(k_x^{(\mathrm t)}x-\omega^{(\mathrm t)}t)}
.$$
(Ignoring the effect of the $y$ coordinate, of course.) Here you can, and it's important to do, fiddle with the amplitudes to make sure that the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side, but unless the exponents on all of the exponentials match exactly, there is absolutely no way that you'll be able to maintain the equality across all times $t$ and all positions $x$ along the boundary. Thus, you require all the temporal frequencies, and all the along-the-surface wavenumbers, to match.

Comment: Ok, but this is a precise boundary condition. Is there any particular reason why Jackson claims that this is a consequence of the mere existence of a condition and that the detailed form doesn't matter? Moreover the electric field is known not to be always continuous (when surface charge is present).

Comment: It's just that general of a statement, to be honest. If you don't have both of those conditions, then no matter what all you'll get is noodle soup instead of anything that makes sense.

Comment: So, let's say that I ignore what Jackson says and use the above condition you wrote. How can I prove that the only solution to that equation are the relations I wrote? Maybe there can be others way to satisfy the equation.

Comment: No, that's not the case, because if the exponents don't match then the exponentials are linearly independent, and the only possible solution would be with all coefficients set to zero.

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew that exponentials are linearly indipendent. What happens if some surface charge is present? In this case the electric field is no more continuous and the same argument leads me to think that the above relations are no longer valid and then also the snell's law falls, but I think that snell's law should be more general. Am I right?

Comment: I found out that exponentials are linearly indipendent only if the exponent is real. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: Nope, that's incorrect. Exponentials are linearly independent for arbitrary complex exponents. I'm not particularly interested in a debate along that kind of tone, though.

Comment: I am very sorry! I did not wanted to look rude. Please forgive my attitude, in fact I am really appreciating your help. Thank you, by the way. You can find the reason why now I think complex exponentials can't be linearly indipendent in the comments of this other question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314765/not-physical-result-from-the-presence-of-surface-charge-density-between-dielectr?noredirect=1#comment707097_314765. You would be very kind to give a look to them.

Comment: That's not an argument that the exponentials are linearly independent - you would need an equation of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N e^{\alpha_i x}\equiv 0$ for *all* relevant $x$ for the functions to be linearly dependent. (For $N$ exponentials with distinct exponents, all you need is sampling at $N$ distinct points, real or complex.) If all you want is evaluation at a single point, real exponentials are no different: try for example $e^x= \frac12 e^{2x}+\frac12 e^{3x}$, which holds at $x=0$.

Comment: As you can guess now I'm starting to get really confused about that. I don't have doubts that you're right, but I think it should be useful for me to read a mathematical proof that complex exponentials are linearly indipendent. Everything I can find on the web is explicitly assuming that the exponents are real. Do you know where I can find a more general proof? Thank you again, you're very kind.

Comment: Quick note: it's independent, not indipendent.

Comment: Thank you also for that! Noted, I'll try not to make the same mistake again.

Comment: My favourite proof takes $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k e^{a_k x}\equiv 0$, differentiates zero through $n$ times, and evaluates at $x=0$ to obtain $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k a_k^j = 0$ for $j=0,\cdots n-1$, where the matrix $(a_k^j)$ is of Vandermonde form; you can then prove by induction that its determinant is the product of all the differences $a_{k_1}-a_{k_2}$. However, even if proofs claim to consider only real-valued exponents, it would be surprising to find one that actually crucially depended on that restriction.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has been one of the most useful I ever received. Sorry if I got confused about the linear independence of exponentials, but I must admit I never applied the idea of linear independence to functions before you mentioned it. My bad of course. I closed this question and I'm going to move the discussion to the other question now.